# Sign vs hash HTTP body request

Tags: oauth2, integrity, openid-connect, request-signing

I use OAuth2 `private_key_jwt` authentication scheme to authenticate clients. Also, I need to be sure that request body isn't modified.

I see two ways:

1. In token which I use to authenticate client I can add claim that contains hash of entire request body
2. Also, in token used to authenticate client I can add claim that contains another public key which as server I can use to verify signed entire request body

The way 1 seems really flexible in comparison to way 2 (I have exprience with way 2, it wasn't something enjoyable but rather frustrating).

But what about security? To add more context, I can say that I use mechanism to prevent replay attacks so the JWT used to authenticate user can be used only once.

One problematic thing I can see is that many request bodies will be the same and have the same hash. But I don't know if this is a security problem and this seems pretty easy to workaround as we can set nonce in header every request and include it in hash.

Maybe there are other even safer and more flexible ways about which I don't know as I'm not security expert?

And what about responses? Can I e.g. sign only hash of entire body or rather should I sign whole response body?

Comment: Please describe what kind of replay attacks do you mean. 1) If you use TLS, then an attacker cannot do replay attack just because TLS makes it impossible. 2) If you mean that user can do that? But user can send the same request as many times as user wants. User is *eligible* to do that. Then at what points do you see the possibility of replay attack?

Comment: I mean scenario where attacker can decrypt request and get JWT used to authentication. Then attacker would be able to construct any request and authenticate using this JWT until it expires. I have mechanism that prevent it.

Comment: Nobody can decrypt TLS.

Comment: The only way to decrypt TLS is to obtain the server private key. If you consider the case, when the attacker has the server private key, then for the attacker it will make no sense to replay the requests, because many of them can be rejected on the application level because of some business rules, e.g. requests means payment of some order, and since this order was paid by the previous request, the replayed requests will be rejected because of business logic...

Comment: ... Instead, the attacker would implement more specific scenario, which is correct from the point of view of business logic. E.g. change delivery address for some purchase, or transfer money to some other account, etc. Means, protection against replayed requests makes little sense if the **server private key** is compromised. And if you believe that you server private key cannot be compromised, then replay attack is impossible.

Comment: Ok, I gave stupid example, but it's still useful in many cases where the JWT used to authentication is leaked. It could leak e.g. in logs or some attack on server memory (e.g. without nonce client is able to store long-life JWT and then it can leak while this attack). Also, I didn't say, but mechanism that I use prevents pre-generation attacks (e.g. by employees).

Comment: 1) Normally JWT is issued for some period of time, like 5 min. The short validity time reduces possible problems in case user account was compromised, JWT was stolen and reused. 2) Usually JWT is signed. Additionally, it can also be encrypted. That's why it cannot be changed. 3) Are you going, for every request, first retrieve a new one-time JWT, and then send request with this JWT to the application?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to do this using server-generated nonce as described in https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-dpop-12.html#name-dpop-proof-pre-generation. But I said it only for better context, I don't think it's important to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141901/discussion-between-mentallurg-and-szyszka947).